# цвет тектса при изминении значения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть код, который обновляет каждые 5 секунд div#result выводит значение стоимости .
как сделать чтобы если значение растёт, текст становиться зелёным, а если падает то красным.

```
var reloadData = function() {
  $.getJSON('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd', function(data){
    var float = parseFloat(data.ticker.price).toFixed(2)
    $('#result').text(float)
  })
}

setInterval('reloadData()', 5000)
$(document).ready(reloadData)
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">Loading...</div>
```

Пример [тут](https://exmo.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Надо просто сравнить текущее значение с предыдущим и в зависимости от результата изменить значение `color` для текста, как-то так :

```js
var reloadData = function() {
  var float = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var prev = parseFloat($('#result').text());

  var color = float >= prev ? 'green' : 'red';      
  $('#result').text(float).css('color', color);
}

setInterval(reloadData, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">0</div>
```